# Unity Framework 2.0 Type config without config file and constructor parameter

Tags: c#, unity-container

I have a class like:

```
public class CustomDatabase : Database
{
    public CustomDatabase(string connString, ILogger logger)
    {
    }
}
```

for example I can use the following config section to config a type and constructor parameters

```
      <type type="Database" mapTo="UnityExamples.Common.CustomDatabase, UnityExamples.Common">
        <typeConfig extensionType="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.TypeInjectionElement,  Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration">
          <constructor>
            <param name="connString" parameterType="System.String">
              <value value="connection value..."/>
            </param>
            <param name="logger" parameterType="ILogger">
              <dependency />
            </param>
          </constructor>
        </typeConfig>
      </type>
```

But how can I convert this section into pure C# code configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
container.RegisterType<Database, CustomDatabase>(new InjectionConstructor("someConnectionString", typeof(ILogger)));
```